# AS3 Error 1009 : Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

Main.as

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public var _root:MovieClip;

    public var monsterContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();


    public var delay = 30;

    public function Main(){
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
    }

    function beginClass(e):void{
        _root = MovieClip(root);
    }

    function enterFrameEvents(e):void{

        addChild(monsterContainer);
        delay -= 1;
        if(delay <= 0){
            var spawn:Slime = new Slime();
            spawn.x = startPoint.x;
            spawn.y = startPoint.y;
            monsterContainer.addChild(spawn);
            delay = 30;
        }

    }
}
```

Arrow.as

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;

public class Arrow extends MovieClip {
    public var _root:MovieClip;

    public var facingID;

    public function Arrow(){
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
    }

    function beginClass(e):void{
        _root = MovieClip(root);
    }

    function enterFrameEvents(e):void{

        trace(_root.monsterContainer == null);

    }
}
```

and in the output it's appear like this :

```
false 
false
false
false
false
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Arrow/enterFrameEvents()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Arrow/enterFrameEvents()
```

at first it say false because trace(_root.monsterContainer == null), but it's suddenly said error 1009, when i used ctrl+shift+enter, it's pointing to trace(_root.monsterContainer == null);

i was try tis for 2 days, please help

the other code :(it's actually maybe not related)

Enemy.as

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;

public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
    public var _root:MovieClip;

    //Status
    public var monsterSpeed;
    public var facing = "Right";

    //CallingArrow
    public var down:Down = new Down();

    public function Enemy(){
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
    }

    function beginClass(e):void{
        _root = MovieClip(root);
    }

    function enterFrameEvents(e):void{

        //Facing Movement
        if(_root.pausing == false){
            if(facing == "Right"){
                this.x += monsterSpeed;
            }else if(facing == "Left"){
                this.x -= monsterSpeed;
            }else if(facing == "Down"){
                this.y += monsterSpeed;
            }else if(facing == "Up"){
                this.y -= monsterSpeed;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Down.as

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;


public class Down extends Arrow {

    public function Down(){

        facingID = "Down";
    }
}
```

Slime.as

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;


public class Slime extends Enemy {

    public function Slime(){

        monsterSpeed = 5;

    }
}
```

and there is no additional code on timeline just stop();

if u need the file (cs6): http://www.mediafire.com/download/hz5tptkgftwdipw/Tower_Defense.rar

Comment: It looks like somehow _root is becoming null. If monsterContainer were null, it wouldn't throw an error, you would just get a trace of true.

Comment: yes it should be just traced as true, but idk why suddenly error 1009 appear, and that's so annyoing, any idea ?

Comment: I suspect you are not showing the full code here. Are you removing the arrow instance? Where are you even instantiating it? It is not visible anywhere...

Comment: @Fygo the other code is not related to this, umm and i don't remove arrow instance, so arrow is just like a .as to tracing the monsterContainer from Main.as

Comment: @YogaAdyaPratama The code where you are manipulating and instantiating the arrow IS related to your question because it is the object that is throwing you the error. It is very unlikely that this would happen unless you changed the '_root', 'monsterContainer, or the arrow instances/references. You must be definitely doing one of that.

Comment: @Fygo i added link to download, please help me sir ![link]http://www.mediafire.com/download/hz5tptkgftwdipw/Tower_Defense.rar

Comment: Try replacing the ADDED event with ADDED_TO_STAGE. The second one only gets dispatched once the object is added to the stage. The first one gets dispatched whenever the object is added to a container, even if the container isn't added to the stage, which could result on root being null.

Comment: @TreeTree i tring to replacing ,but it's still get the same output, it's still null, this is so irritating, i get the logic, but dont get the syntax lol

Comment: i don't see where you are instantiating arrow, but if anything, you should place `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);` inside your `beginClass(e):void` because _root will be null, since it is not given a value yet (obviously you are creating the Arrow instance first then adding it to some container later)

Comment: @MartonPallagi The Down class is being created in the Enemy class. Down is a subclass of Arrow and Slime is a subclass of Enemy. Slime is created in the Main class.

Comment: i get that but neither of those classes are relevant to your problem, as your problem comes from `_root` being null (hence _NULL OBJECT_) and you are asking for the `monsterContainer` property of this _NULL OBJECT_ which is obviously an error. The solution is adding the enter frame eventlistener only **after** `_root = MovieClip(root)` has been called.

Comment: @TreeTree Wow ! Thank you mister the problem is "The Down class is being created in the Enemy class", actually i don't need it, and when i delete it, perfect it works ! Thank you very much sir

Comment: @MartonPallagi it's now fixed sir, i delete the 'public var down:Down = new Down();' and works perfectly, thank you for any help

Comment: i'm glad it works but that didn't fix the problem itself:) your problem is that when you create an Arrow instance ie.: `public var down:Down = new Down();` all the superclass constructors run, therefore the Arrow constructor will run, which will add an event listener asking for _root.monsterContainer ! But the Down class has no idea about anything because it has just been created! The solution is in my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
public function Arrow(){
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
}

function beginClass(e):void{
    _root = MovieClip(root);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
}
```

In your code `_root` will be *NULL*, because your object may not be added to the stage in the same frame so

```
function enterFrameEvents(e):void{

    trace(_root.monsterContainer == null);

}
```

will try to access the `monsterContainer` property of a *NULL* object. Hence the good old #1009

Comment: obviously same goes for every other class where applicable ie: Enemy